# How to type iterator results using generators in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using typescript and I created the following code

```
function* myIter(): Iterator<number> {
    yield 3;
    yield 2;
    yield 1;
}

const iter: Iterator<number> = myIter();
const item:IteratorYieldResult<number> = iter.next();
```

[DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mAVAAgLYE8CSUCmAnACgEoAuZbfAQyjjwB4wRUAjfAPmQG8AoZP5dDBwAbACbIAzAG5e-QSPEAmGfwFCxyAIwyAvt24QEAZyjIYuPGQp5qtBk1Z4OAXjRYLxGYbAmzuVCTWtngAmuqiAEo4RiDCUPYs7Miu5vgAdGA4AB5QnkA)

It produces a typescript error

[image]

Telling me on hover what the error is

[image]

I checked what exactly `next` is returning and found this interface definition:

```
interface Iterator<T, TReturn = any, TNext = undefined> {
    // NOTE: 'next' is defined using a tuple to ensure we report the correct assignability errors in all places.
    next(...args: [] | [TNext]): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
    return?(value?: TReturn): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
    throw?(e?: any): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
}
```

And this is the point where I get lost, because my iterator is defined as `Iteractor<number>` so what is `TReturn`. On the other hand it is by default set to `any` so I guess it is optional and I can leave it out. But for some reason it doesn't work that way with `IteratorResult`. Anyway, some guidance would be appreciated?

I'm unsure what the problem is here, but maybe someone can help me out with this one?

Comment: I think the actual type for the generator function should be `IterableIterator<>` if i'm not mistaken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've shown, the `next()` method of an iterator returns a value of type `IteratorResult`.  This is [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L41) as:

```
type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> 
  | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
```

, a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of `IteratorYieldResult` and `IteratorReturnResult`, themselves [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L31-L39) like this:

```
interface IteratorYieldResult<TYield> {
    done?: false;
    value: TYield;
}

interface IteratorReturnResult<TReturn> {
    done: true;
    value: TReturn;
}
```

That means the compiler is telling you that `iter.next()` is returning *either* an `IteratorYieldResult` object with a `false`/missing `done` property, and a `value` of type `number`, *or* it is returning an `IteratorReturnResult` object with a *`true`* `done` property, and a `value` of type `any`.

You are assigning that to a variable of type `IteratorYieldResult`, and the compiler is telling you "wait, it might *not* be that type.  It *could* be an `IteratorReturnResult`".

Now, since you wrote the generator yourself, you know that the first time you call `next()` you're going to get an `IteratorYieldResult` because there are three `yield` statements before the function returns.  But that's information the type system just doesn't have.  It's like this:

```
function foo(): number | string {
    return "hello";
}
const str: string = foo(); // error! number not assignable to string
```

The function `foo()` returns either a `number` or a `string`, according to its type signature.  You can tell that it will always return a `string`, but the compiler cannot tell this, because it's just looking at the signature, not drilling down into the implementation.  And so it complains: "hey, maybe `str` will be a `number` at runtime, not a `string` as you are claiming".

---

So what's the "right" thing to do here?  I guess it depends on what you're trying to do.  In this toy example, you can just tell the compiler that is doesn't need to worry and that you are *sure* to get an `IteratorYieldResult` and not an `IteratorReturnResult`.  And this sort of "telling" the compiler that something is of a narrower type than it can verify is done via a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const itemAsserted = iter.next() as IteratorYieldResult<number>; // okay
```

Or, you can do the general check where you *don't* claim to know what's coming out (which makes sense if the implementation of `myIter()` might change, or if you're doing `iter.next()` in a loop):

```
const itemSafe = iter.next();
// const itemSafe: IteratorResult<number, any>
if (!itemSafe.done) {
    itemSafe; // const itemSafe: IteratorYieldResult<number>
    itemSafe.value.toFixed(); // okay
}
```

Here we are just letting the compiler tell us that `iter.next()` returns an `IteratorResult<number, any>`.  Then we take that returned value and *test* it by checking the `done`property.  If it's not `true`, then the compiler helpfully narrows the result down to `IteratorYieldResult<number>` for you.  You don't need to assert anything because the compiler understands the kind of type checking done above; it's because `IteratorResult` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), where a single property (in this case `done`) can be checked to figure out which member of the union you're looking at.

---

Okay, I hope that makes sense to you and is helpful.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhAhAKAlALmRMAWwCMBTAJ2QB9kBnGcuCAc2QG9hkvlzSYxyKAEQALUgBtxCIQG5gAX2BQk9Ogzz1GLZAF5U6bDOQB6Y8grkE5AIT4iZShAQxkAQ1q04zCK+LjSyDAIalrMwOHg0PBIAFTIhACeAJIwFNh4KRSuQeQAPAQkFAB87JzcCXASACbIAMxy3MgV1cgATA3lleI1AIxyikoqLnCp5Bmj2Vb59sW68cmjhuHKEKojpIQAgh4UqTV66+QAdBCkAB4w2G60yJnkk+QAml1VAEqktGDiMNOF5EVGUzIBAAa1cCWWQ2Q60IAGVXCAAgdRidzpcsHIgSs1qk4QjSOMsjl3p9vr8HAAaNwQBJFYBwEDIDDWGHwxFHKpIUhYUqNVn4wFmbHDXFsgm3CY5Z7VElfH4FBx0vmi-FHABurnEYFIRyCADE4GdSFVDCYzKDwQpwsAgA)

Comment: Why is the `done` property optional? According to MDN, the `done` property would always exist.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like having to check `done` at every callsite since I know exactly how many elements my stream should contain, so I wrote a little wrapper that simplifies the return value of `next()`:

```
export class SimpleIterator<T> {
    constructor(private generator: AsyncGenerator<T>) {
    }

    async next(): Promise<T> {
        const {value, done} = await this.generator.next()
        if(done) throw new Error("Reached end of stream")
        return value
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
const iter = new simpleIterator(getSomeAsyncGenerator())
const value = await iter.next()
```

It's not a true "iterator" in that it doesn't implement the interator interface so you can't use it in a `for` but that's not how I wanted to use it anyway (generators are already `for`-able so just use it directly if you want that)